# How to re-use async callback function?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am using `async.parallel` in two functions with same callback function
. In second function (`two()`) added third function as addition function

```
function one(){
var testuser = 1;
 async.parallel([onefunction, secondfunction], function(err, result){...})
}

function two(){
var testuser = 2;
async.parallel([onefunction, secondfunction, thirdfunction], function(err, result){...})
}

function onefunction(callback){....code with testuser......}
function twofunction(callback){....code with testuser......}
function thirdfunction(callback){....code with testuser......}
```

Q : How can I access testuser value in `onefunction`, `secondfunction` and `thirdfunction`.

Now I get **undefined err**. I also tried as normal parameter pass logic `onefunction(testuser)`, but its not working.

I want to use `onefunction`, `twofunction` in multiple cases...how can I do that?

Comment: Make it a parameter of the functions and pass it to them.

Comment: @FelixKling can u explain in brief? you mean to say `onefunction(testuser)`

Comment: Well, you will also have to pass `callback` I assume. And since you have to pass functions to `async.parallel` (so it seems), it should be `callback => onefunction(testuser, callback)`, etc.

Comment: @PrashantTapase Where is the `secondfunction` definition? I can see only `twofunction` declared.

Comment: @FelixKling : thanks. atleast it is not giving error. will test and mark as answer

Comment: @PrashantTapase Just a suggestion, for your next question keep the code executable and show us the error logs in details. So that someone can help you very quickly. Check the following answer too. Happy Coding ;)

Comment: @FelixKling : can share some good tutorial or explain me code. how your code is working/logic? so it will useful for me for next time.

Comment: @PrashantTapase: Can you comment on my answer if its not working for you ?

Comment: @Felix King  in your answer you are using ES6 arrow function right .. ?

Comment: @sudeep_dk: Its understood from his code. And ES6 is the top most favourite feature used by all. FYR [survey link](http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1454335895es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-and-concise-syntax-in-js01-axel-rauschmayer-survey-favorite-es6-features.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Felix suggested,

```
function one(){
var testuser = 1;
 async.parallel([onefunction, secondfunction], function(err, result){...})
}

    function two(){
    var testuser = 2;
    async.parallel([
       callback => onefunction(testuser, callback), 
       callback => twofunction(testuser, callback), 
       callback => thirdfunction(testuser, callback)], function(err, result){...})
    }

    function onefunction(callback){....code with testuser......}
    function twofunction(callback){....code with testuser......}
    function thirdfunction(callback){....code with testuser......}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how can I access `testuser` value in `onefunction`, `secondfunction` & so on.. 
**Code:**

```
var async = require('async');

function one(){
    var testuser = 1;
    //You can bind a context here; remember to pass the context i.e. null for this, otherwise it won't work as expected.
    async.parallel({one_func:onefunction.bind(null,testuser), two_func:twofunction.bind(null,testuser)}, function(err, result){
        console.log("In one()");
        console.log("err",err);
        console.log("result",result); //result array with all task's results e.g. one_func, two_func
        console.log("testuser",testuser);
 })
}

function onefunction(testuser,cb){
    console.log('onefunction');
    return cb(null,{"testuser":testuser});
}

function twofunction(testuser,cb){
    console.log('twofunction');
    return cb(null,{"testuser":testuser});
}

one();
```

**Update:** Answer for your another question in title about reusing callbacks.

You can reuse named function as callback?

**Example code:**

```
function one(){
    var testuser = 1;
    async.parallel({one_func:onefunction.bind(null,testuser), two_func:twofunction.bind(null,testuser)},calback)
}

function calback (err, result){
        console.log("calback"); //You can reuse this named function as callbacks
        console.log("err",err);
        console.log("result",result);
 }
```

Comment: `callback => onefunction(testuser, callback)` this code is working for me.. thanks amol for try

Comment: @PrashantTapase: Could you post your own answer here (& accept it), so that it helps others as well. Thank you :)

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni chk